# Can we synonymize clone and cloning?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tag-synonyms

Can we synonymize [clone](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/clone) and [cloning](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/cloning)?

They are basically the same thing. Both are being used for questions about cloning machines (desktops and servers), or cloning hard drives. [clone](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/clone) is the one being used more, with more accepted answers and score, but it doesn't have a description. We could copy over the description from [cloning](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/cloning).

I don't have enough score on any of them to suggest the "synonymization" <sub>(boy, what a word)</sub>, hence the question.

Comment: As always a bit of clean sweep should be mandatory before any action.

Comment: I'm contemplating retaging all "cloning" to be "clone", but that's useless anyways; that's the whole point of synonyms.

Comment: @Braiam You might need to explain what you think should be "mandatory" here. It doesn't make any sense to me simply when merging two tags.

Comment: @KevinBowen well, when I asked to synonymize `sleep` and `suspend`, nobody bothered to check if `sleep` was well used, now we have questions with `sleep` the bash command that means 'wait' without checking. That is what I mean by mandatory verification.

Answer (score 4):

[clone](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/clone) and [cloning](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/cloning) are used interchangeably, and largely in accordance with the description in the [cloning](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/cloning) tag wiki.

I only spotted a handful of questions that didn't fit, and I retagged them:

- Distributed version control: [1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333343/git-cloning-error)
- Multiple monitors: [1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34083/clone-screen-default-projector) [2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256012/no-sound-via-hdmi-and-i-cannot-use-mirror-display-on-a-lenovo-g560)
- Users: [1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/196998/how-to-clone-root-user-in-ubuntu)

I prefer the name “cloning” since the questions are about the cloning activity, not about a clone. It's also the name [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) [uses](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/cloning). [Super User](https://superuser.com/) has both.

Comment: Yeah, I also prefer the name cloning. I'm not sure if it's possible to "synonymize" them then make all of them tagged as "cloning", but if it is, then that's great!

Comment: @Alaa Moderators can make the two tags synonym. (There's a voting process to do it without moderator intervention, but the [requirements](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) are too high to be practical, and [tag:clone] would have to be the main tag because it has more occurrences.)

Comment: Yup, I know the process =), but I didn't know that the one with more occurrences becomes the main tag. Can it not be manually changed to be cloning?

Comment: @Alaa Moderators can set it up either way. Moderators can even synonymize a tag to a non-existing tag, which effectively means renaming a tag.

Comment: So you're saying you can't start the process to synonymize them because you don't have a score of 5 or more in clone? I thought it was the other way around.

Comment: @Seth You need a sufficient score in the main tag. Nobody except moderators can start the synonym process to make [tag:cloning] the main tag. If [tag:clone] is to be the main tag, there is [only one user (soon 2)](http://askubuntu.com/tags/clone/topusers) who can propose the synonym (not counting moderators), and 7 more who could vote for it.

Comment: @Gilles Why can only mods make [tag:cloning] the main tag? You have a score of 6 in it.

Comment: @Seth The main tag has to have more occurrences than the proposed synonym, or at least almost as many (I forget what the exact threshold is). At a 4:1 ratio, only [tag:clone] can be the main tag unless a moderator intervenes.